# Timeout occurred when trying to send messages from firebase admin

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Am trying to send notifications to all registered users from firebase admin every 2 hours with pubsub schedule function

This is code am deploying in firebase functions

```
exports.scheduledFunction =functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 hours').onRun((context) => {
console.log('This will be run every 2 hours!');
listAllUsers(undefined)});
function listAllUsers(nextPageToken) {
// List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
admin.auth().listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
.then(function(listUsersResult) {
    listUsersResult.users.forEach(function(userRecord) {
      pushCheckMessageNotification(userRecord.customClaims['latest']);
    });
    if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
        // List next batch of users.
        listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
    }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error listing users:', error);
});
}

function pushCheckMessageNotification(token){
const promise = [];
promise.push(admin.messaging().send(
 {
    data: {
        body: "Test",
        title: "Test",
        chat: "CHECK_MESSAGES"
    },
    android:{
        priority: "high"
    },
    token: '' + token,
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Pushed notification.");
    console.log("Notify Token", token);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error("Notification push crash", error);
}));

}
```

The below error occurred sometimes and notification not pushed

`{ Error: Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded.
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:152:23
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-timeout',
     message: 'Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded.' },
  codePrefix: 'app' }`

Comment: Can you show us your function ?

Comment: do u get confirmation of at least some message sent? you need to yield the call for `listUsersResult.users.forEach` or return a promise from there, otherwise, your function will be hanging

Comment: Yes sometimes works perfectly. Rarely am getting this timeout error

Comment: Issue is resolved after returning the promise. Thanks Andres.